# Make Error when installing llvm clang tidy

Tags: clang, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to install clang-tidy

I have ran these commands and getting error when executing `sudo make install clang-tidy -j 12`

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build 
cd build
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" ../llvm
sudo make install clang-tidy -j 12
```

Output:

```
[ 68%] ASTNodeAPI.json
/bin/sh: 1: ../../../../bin/clang-ast-dump: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [tools/clang/lib/Tooling/CMakeFiles/obj.clangTooling.dir/build.make:81: tools/clang/lib/Tooling/ASTNodeAPI.json] Error 126
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:45076: tools/clang/lib/Tooling/CMakeFiles/obj.clangTooling.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 68%] Built target arcmt-test
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target obj.clangApplyReplacements
[ 68%] Built target clangTransformer
[ 68%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/extra/clang-apply-replacements/CMakeFiles/obj.clangApplyReplacements.dir/lib/Tooling/ApplyReplacements.cpp.o
[ 68%] Built target clangCrossTU
[ 73%] Built target LLVMCodeGen
[ 73%] Built target obj.clangApplyReplacements
[ 73%] Built target obj.clangReorderFields
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
```

Even after re-starting the process I get the same error

Comment: I suspect the problem is caused by running the build under `sudo`, since that could cause some file permissions to be wrong.  It looks like you are following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811762/2659307) but they do not have `sudo`.  Does the problem happen if you start over and do not use `sudo`?